# What is this white component?

Tags: switches, identification, components

Anybody knows what this component is? (The white cylinder.)

It has to be some kind of switch since it is marked as "S2", but I never saw anything like it before.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It could be a level-sensitive mercury switch.

Comment: Please, provide a better, focused photo. Maybe add another from a different angle of view. As per our guidelines the post should be useful also for other people browsing the site. As it stands, someone that doesn't know that component has  few chances to understand what it is.

Comment: I'd guess a fuse, but calling it s doesn't make sense then. A tilt switch?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the provided image is of very low quality and makes the thread useful only to the OP. Anyone browsing the thread should be able to clearly discern the component that the OP wants to be identified.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati, I can upload as many images as you want, but I think that all will look pretty similar, it is just a small white cylinder. If someone knows this component he/she will recognize it at once and those that don't know it will learn it and recognize it if they find it in the future. Sorry for the low quality, but it is a small component and my phone doesn't focus very well, I can't do it better.

Comment: jap-jap, Posting fuzzy images has no excuse.  Learn how to focus your camera-phone.

Comment: A component identification question should also include as much context as possible. If you _know_ it's in an alarm system, then please put that in the question.

Comment: @Ale..chenski, sure, don't worry, I will study hard for the next time ; )

Comment: @marcelm, yes, you are right. I didn't think about that. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a kind of motion detector.

It looks very much like the [SQ-SEN-200](https://signalquest.com/product/components/sq-sen-200/) from SignalQuest. [Datasheet](https://signalquest.com/download/Tilt%20and%20Vibration%20Sensor%20SQ-SEN-200.pdf)

Picture from the datasheet:

[image]

They are meant to be used in devices that should sleep when not in use, but wake up and do something when moved.

Like a GPS tracker.  You want to record where your cat goes, but don't need 18 hours a day of unchanging GPS coordinates from all the naps it takes.  When the cat naps, no signals from the sensor.  When your cat gets up, the sensor "rattles" its output and your GPS receiver wakes up and takes notes.

That sensor is entirely passive, so it doesn't use battery power like many other kinds of motion detectors.  Well, unless you count 50nA as wasting power.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly that one. Thanks!

Comment: What device did you find it in?

Comment: it is inside of an alarm system so it makes sense. I guess this component will be used to detect when the control board is being manipulated

Comment: Yep.  Intrusion alarm on the control box.  Call the cops whilst the bad guys are still beating on the housing of the controller.